# Backup mysql com create schema

Tags: mysql, ssh

Estou precisando de fazer o *backup* de uma base de dados (DUMP) que venha com `create schema`.

Qual a linha de comando utilizando PUTTY (via SSH) para fazer tal tarefa ?

Pesquisei e achei este comando porém ele faz somente o backup das tabelas e dos dados.

```
mysqldump -h HOST -u LOGIN -pSENHA --opt --routines --triggers BANCO > backup.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comando [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) não só realiza o backup dos dados como também da estrutura do banco. Ele possui diversas opções que geram as saidas que você precisa, como por exemplo `--create-options`, `--add-drop-table` e `--add-drop-database` Na [documentação oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) você pode encontrar todas as opções e suas descrições.

Lembre-se: Para realizar um backup use o comando a seguir:

```
$ mysqldump --opt -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname] > [backupfile.sql]
```

Para restaurar o backup use o comando abaixo:

```
mysql -u [uname] -p[pass] [db_to_restore] < [backupfile.sql]
```